# Access Span Inside Div by means of classname

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to access span inside div by using `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

I have-

```
<div class="PERSON">
    <span class="name">Person_name</span>
    <span class="title">Person_title</span>
    <span class="team">Person_team</span>
</div>
```

I need to access all spans with class team within all divs with class PERSON. How do I do it?

I have the following code -

```
function dispTeam(tname)
{
   alert(tname);
   var e=document.getElementsByClassName("PERSON");
   for(var m=0;m<e.length;m++)
   {
      if(e[m].document.getElementsByClassName("team").innerHTML.indexOf(tname)==-1)
      {
         e[m].style.display="none";
      }
      else
      {
         e[m].style.display="block";
      }
   }
}
```

The alert is getting triggered but the elements are not getting displayed.

NOTE: There are divs with class PERSON which do NOT have span with class team. I need to include those divs in this condition too.

If they don't have span class team, those divs must not be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
dispTeam=function(tname)
{
    var divs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
        divs[i].style.display='none';
    var span=document.querySelectorAll(".PERSON>.team");
    for(var i=0; i<span.length; i++)
    {
        if(span[i].innerHTML.indexOf(tname)!=-1)
            span[i].parentNode.style.display='block';
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b4WXZ/1/)**

Read More: **[`querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()`](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/using-javascripts-css3-selectors.html#fbid=LIiLErykQUn)**